# How to prevent mobile browsers, form input focusing, jumping to a different form?

Tags: html, forms, mobile

When you focus on a form element in a mobile browser, they come up with previous and next icons for easier navigation. However for some reason if I click next to what should be the end of that particular forms' input, if there is another form on the page, pressing next again will make it jump to the second form.

For example I have a log in form on the body of my page like so:

```
<form name="customer_login" id="customer_login" method="post" action="/login">
    Email: <input type="email" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" />
    Passwird: <input type="password" name="customer[password]" id="customer_password" />
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Then further down my page, in the footer I have a separate form for my newsletter:

```
<form name="newsletter" id="newsletter" method="post" action="/newsletter">
    Subscribe: <input type="email" name="email" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" title="Sign Up">Go</button>
</form>
```

But once I'm focused on the password field in the log in form, the next button to me should become disabled or at least not jump to an entirely different form. Is this normal behavior for mobile browsers and forms? Or am I missing a form attribute which is not differentiating the two forms?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tabindex=1` to your input fields...see if that helps. By mobile, you using an iPhone? If so, those < and > arrows are essentially the TAB button on a keyboard, etc.

`tabindex=1` value should increment in the order you want to "tab", etc.

Comment: Still jumps from one form to another after using tabindex, it just seems a bit strange that this is default behavior. Surely if you're filling in one form on a page you are just going to be wanting to stay focused on that form?

Comment: Hmmm...no idea. Could be a bug with Apple

Comment: It's also the same on the Chrome browser on iOS, beginning to think it's intentional, thanks for your input though!